# PDF4NET pdf's not showing the bound content when viewed on iOS default pdf reader

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using Version 4.4.1.0 of O2S.Components.PDF4NET

I am using this in an MVC project to run through a series of 6 views and fill an object with the data required for the PDF.

When the PDF is bound and emailed in the last step it works great. all except for when it is viewed by default PDF reader on iOS devices.

My company purchased this product on the cheaper plan so the 90 support is over and I cannot access any sort of forums from there site.

I read a similar issue regarding a button not being displayed on iOS but there was no resolution other then to email the company.

I hope that there is a viable solution as I would prefer not to have to cut my losses and change to a different product over something as short sighted as not supporting/testing against one of the more common platforms people use to consume media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'bound content' but I assume you are talking about form fields. 
Forms fields and annotations are not displayed by the CGPDF API in iOS, only the main page content is displayed. It is not a limitation of PDF4NET, it is a limitation of the iOS PDF display engine. The workaround is to flatten the form fields thus making them part of the page content.
If this is not your situation, please send a mail to support and they will help you.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET.

Comment: yes by bound content I was meaning form fields.  I have called the FlattenFormFields() method on the pdf just before saving it and it has resolved my issue.  Thank you for the help